# cant launch laravel site

Tags: php, laravel, php-5.6

Ive tried setting up a laravel instance many times now on Ubuntu 16.04 system. I have `php5.6` and `apache2` installed. Installed composer following the instructions on there site and than ran (composer global require "laravel/installer") to install laravel.

I've added (`export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`) to .bashrc and then create new laravel project with laravel new project. to test if it was working I cd into project and ran (php artisan serve) but keep coming up with

```
PHP Warning:  require(/home/dave/project/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/dave/project/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/dave/project/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/dave/project/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

Can anyone help get me going.

Comment: Check project directory permissioms permissions and group. Check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/a/37266353/4841755.

Comment: @Viktor (drwxrwxr-x 11 dave dave    4096 Apr 25 10:53 project) are the permissions set for the folder

Comment: what about group ```www-data``` for the project folder (recursively, for all child directories)?

Comment: Have you run `composer install` in the project directory? If so, does the directory `vendor` exist in the project directory?